# Using any_of inside of filter R

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to use an an `any_of()` within a `filter()` to handle variable names that may or may not be in a dataframe when I run a function across it. When doing this however I run across the error that `any_of() must be used within a *selecting* function.`
Is it possible to create something that can non-specificity or do I need to create a method to name the expected column explicitly?

I've made a quick little example that shows the issue and would be very interested in any work arounds or suggestions.

```
data("iris")

iris %>%
  mutate(Sepal.Area = Sepal.Length*Sepal.Width,
         Petal.Area = Petal.Length*Petal.Width) %>%
  filter(if_all(starts_with("Sepal"), ~.>4),
         any_of(c("Petal.Area", "Petal.Diameter"), ~.>2))
```

Comment: I think you need `if_any()` instead of `any_of()` just as you used `if_all()` instead of `all_of()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may have to wrap with `if_all` over the `any_of` or use `matches`

```
iris %>%
  mutate(Sepal.Area = Sepal.Length*Sepal.Width,
         Petal.Area = Petal.Length*Petal.Width)  %>% 
  filter(if_all(starts_with("Sepal"), ~ .x > 4),   
          if_all(matches("Petal.Area|Petal.Diameter"), ~ .x  > 2))
```

---

OR may need

```
iris %>%
    filter(if_all(any_of(c("Petal.Length", "hello")), ~ .x > 2), 
        if_all(starts_with("Sepal"), ~ .x > 4))
```

---

These are two different cases - `any_of` **selects** only the columns that are found in the dataset without returning an error if there are some columns not found, whereas `if_all` loops over the columns selected and returns TRUE for a row only if all the columns under selection returns TRUE based on the condition (`if_any` - returns TRUE if any of the columns selected are TRUE). e.g.

```
> d1 <- data.frame(col1 = 1:3, col2 = -1:1, col3 = 2:4)
# col4 is not found
> d1 %>%
    filter(if_all(any_of(c("col1", "col2", "col4")), ~ .x > 0))
  col1 col2 col3
1    3    1    4

> d1 %>%
   filter(if_any(c("col1", "col2", "col4"), ~ .x > 0))
Error in `filter()`:
! Problem while expanding `..1 = if_any(c("col1", "col2", "col4"), ~.x > 0)`.
Caused by error in `if_any()`:
! Can't select columns that don't exist.
✖ Column `col4` doesn't exist.

> d1 %>%
   filter(if_any(c("col1", "col2", "col3"), ~ .x > 0))
  col1 col2 col3
1    1   -1    2
2    2    0    3
3    3    1    4
```

Comment: The `filter(if_all(any_of(c("x", "y", "z"))))` solution is exactly the trick that worked for me. Thanks!